# For $f(I\setminus\{0\})=\left (\frac{(1+h(x))^{1/h(x)}}{e}\right)^{1/x}$ find $\lim_{x \to 0}f(x) = \sqrt{1/e^{h'(0)}}$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, taylor-expansion

The subject is *Taylor and Malcaurin polynomials*.

Let $h(x)$ be a continuous function on the interval $I\ni x=0$.

Differentiable at $x = 0$

And: 
$$h(x):=\begin{cases}0,&x=0\\y\in(-1,+\infty)\setminus\{0\},&x\in I\setminus\{0\}\end{cases}
$$

Define:

$$
f(I\setminus\{0\}) = \left(\frac{(1+h(x))^{\frac{1}{h(x)}}}{e}\right)^{\frac{1}{x}}$$
Show that: 
$$
\lim_{x \to 0}f(x) =\sqrt{\frac{1}{e^{h'(0)}}}
$$

The hint for the ex. was to take $\ln(f(x))$

---

What I did:

As the hint suggested, I did $\ln(f(x))$

And got to: 
$$
\ln(f(x)) = \frac{1}{xh(x)}\ln(1+h(x)) - \frac{1}{x} = \frac{1}{x}\left(\frac{1}{h(x)}\ln(1+h(x)) - 1\right)
$$

I looked at the term I need to get to. I see $h'(0)$.

Therefore, I developed a *Maclaurin polynomial*:

$$
P_n(x) = h(0) + h'(0)x + R_n(x) = 0 + h'(0) + R_n(x)
$$

And now I am pretty stuck.

I thought to make a *Maclaurin* for $\ln(1+h(x))$ instead, maybe, but also, I don't see it bringing me anywhere.

Can I have a hint?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: You should proceed with algebraic manipulation to get the expression as $$\frac{\log(1+h(x))-h(x)}{(h(x))^2}\cdot \frac{h(x)} {x} $$ Now you can easily get the limit of both factors.

Answer (score 1):

Starting from 
$$\ln(f(x))=\frac{1}{xh(x)}(\ln(1+h(x))-h(x))$$
and using the Taylor series at $x=0$ for $\ln(1+x)$, that is, 
 $$\ln(1+x)=\sum_{n\geq 0}\frac{(-1)^nx^{n+1}}{n+1}$$
you have that 
$$\frac{1}{xh(x)}(\ln(1+h(x))-h(x))=\frac{1}{x}\left(-\frac{h(x)}{2}+h(x)F(h(x))\right)=-\frac{h(x)}{x}+\frac{h(x)}{x}F(h(x))$$
where $F(h(x))\to 0$ when $x\to 0.$ Because $h$ is differentiable at $x=0$, and $h(0)=0$ you get 
$$\lim_{x\to 0}\ln f(x)=-\frac{h'(0)}{2}.$$